# Is there a way to select a particular set of cells on a google sheet and copy them to another sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have two sheets in a spreadsheet.

Spreadsheet 1 gets updated with new data that goes to a master list.
Spreadsheet 2 is the master list.

Each week spreadsheet 1 gets new data and it could be between 30 and 50 entries long going from B2 to B(N), it depends on how much data was collected over the week.

The masterlist has all the previous data entries.

I'm looking to make a script that selects all the new data in column 'B' from spreadsheet 1, copy them and paste only the values to the end of the masterlist on column 'C'.

I've gotten to the point with a separate script where it just selects the mastersheet and selects a cell just after data is filled: (e.g. if the masterlist has 400 entries, it selects cell 401).

Any guidance on this would be fantastic

```
function jump() {
  //Moves to the masterlist sheet and finds the last row filled with data and moves down by one
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var activeSheet = ss.getSheetByName('masterlist'); //source sheet
  var obSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  
  activeSheet.activate() //Move to the source sheet
  
  //Move to the last filled row w/data and go down by 1
  var values = activeSheet.getRange("C:C").getValues();
  var maxIndex = values.reduce(function(maxIndex, row, index) {
    return row[0] === "" ? maxIndex : index;
  }, 0);
  activeSheet.setActiveRange(activeSheet.getRange(maxIndex + 2, 3));
};
```

Comment: Your script moves to the last row in masterlist and activates().  It doesn't try to move data at all.

Comment: Yes...I'm aware. That's what I'm trying to figure out. I posted that code to see if I could build upon what I've already done to add the extra functionality that I'm looking for

Comment: You could have just used Sheet.getLastRow() instead of calculating maxIndex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function AWayToCopyDataFromOneRangeToAnother() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  sh2.clear();
  const rg1=sh1.getRange(1,1,sh1.getLastRow(),sh1.getLastColumn());
  const rg2=sh2.getRange(1,1);
  rg1.copyTo(rg2);
}
```

[copyTo](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copyTo(Range))

```
function AWayToCopyDataFromOneRangeToAnotherSpreadSheetValuesOnly() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const ss2=SpreadsheetApp.openById('1VsHWPCWE6Xz4BLjVK89rnonBZO-8tK5HW_O-mMwFe54');
  const sh2=ss2.getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  sh2.clear();
  const rg1=sh1.getRange(1,1,sh1.getLastRow(),sh1.getLastColumn());
  const vs1=rg1.getValues();
  sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,1,vs1.length,vs1[0].length).setValues(vs1);
  
}
```

[setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Comment: The second option: copyTo is like super close to what I was trying to do :) Here's what I modded however:  `function copyToEndOfMasterlist() {
  const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh1=ss.getSheetByName('7/24');
  const sh2=ss.getSheetByName('OB DNC-FPBX-Master-WIP');
  const rg1=sh1.getRange(2,2,sh1.getLastRow(),sh1.getLastColumn());
  const vs1=rg1.getValues();
  sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,3,vs1.length,vs1[0].length).setValues(vs1);
  sh2.activate();
};`

Comment: Ok, didn't realize if I tried to put the code here it would be so messed up as a comment. Lemme know if you need me to clarify

Comment: Ok, after some playing around with it, I got it to work perfectly the way I want it to. Thanks a lot cooper :) I'll post what worked for me

Answer (score 0):

```
function copyToEndOfMasterlist() {
```

`const ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();`

`const sh1=ss.getSheetByName('sheet1');`

`const sh2=ss.getSheetByName('Masterlist');`

`const rg1=sh1.getRange(2,2,sh1.getLastRow(),sh1.getLastColumn());`

`const vs1=rg1.getValues();`

`sh2.getRange(sh2.getLastRow()+1,3,vs1.length,vs1[0].length).setValues(vs1);`

`};`